# C++ get acces to class variable

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

Dear StackOverflowers,

I am learning to code object-oriented C++. For a project, I'm programming an esp32 using the Arduino core. I have the following problem:

I have a class called `ULAM`, which contains an array of objects of a class called `program` and an object of a class called `screen`.

```
class ULAM {
private:
  UlamProgram programs[10];
  UlamScreen screen;
}
```

the class `program` has a `public` variable `String name`

```
class UlamProgram {
public:
  String name;
}
```

from a function within `screen` I want to access the variable `String name`

```
void UlamScreen::programScreen() {
        tft.println(programs[0].name);
  }
```

How can I get acces to this variable? I tried a couple of things already but I can't get it to work.

What I tried is to pass the `programs` array as a parameter to the `screen` constructor, but I can't figure out how to do this exactly. Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: you cannot access private variables outside of a class, you need to add a getter for this in `ULAM` class that will return a pointer or a reference (best make it const) to that data. The problem is not that you cannot access `name`, but you cannot access `programs` as this is a private variable in another class.

Comment: since you declared programs private you can't access the array, so you add an accessor function in ULAM e.g. `public: UlamProgram& ULAM::Programs(int index) { return programs[index];}` and then call that in your function programScreen instead.